# Socket Programming: Error on listen()

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

I'm working on a server part of my app and I came across a problem I can't seem to solve. The server initialization function, which is a part of `ConnectionManager` class, is as follows:

```
int ConnectionManager::init_server() {

    // Log
    OutputDebugString(L"> Initializing server...\n");

    // Initialize winsock
    WSAData wsa;
    int code = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (code != 0) {
        // Error initializing winsock
        OutputDebugString(L"> Log: WSAStartup()\n");
        output_error(code);
        return -1;
    }

    // Get server information
    struct addrinfo hints, *serverinfo, *ptr;
    SOCKET sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_protocol = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;

    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &serverinfo) != 0) {
        // Error when getting server address information
        OutputDebugString(L"> Log: getaddrinfo()\n");
        output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // Call Cleanup?
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = serverinfo; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        // Create socket
        if ((sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            // Error when creating a socket
            OutputDebugString(L"> Log: socket()\n");
            output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // Call Cleanup?
            continue;
        }

        // Set options
        const char enable = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Error when setting options
            OutputDebugString(L"> log: setsockopt()\n");
            output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // call cleanup?
            if (closesocket(sockfd) != 0) {
                output_error(WSAGetLastError());
            }
            return -1;
        }

        // Bind socket
        if (bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Error on binding
            OutputDebugString(L"> Log: bind()\n");
            output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // Call Cleanup?
            if (closesocket(sockfd) != 0) {
                output_error(WSAGetLastError());
            }
            continue;
        }    

        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(serverinfo);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        OutputDebugString(L"Error: Failed to launch server.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Listen
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        OutputDebugString(L"> Log: listen()\n");
        output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // Call Cleanup?;
        return -1;
    }
    // Accept
    struct sockaddr_storage clientinfo;
    int size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
    m_exchfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientinfo, &size);
    if (m_exchfd = INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // Error when accepting
        OutputDebugString(L"> Log: accept()\n");
        output_error(WSAGetLastError()); // Call Cleanup?
        if (closesocket(sockfd) != 0) {
            output_error(WSAGetLastError());
        }
        return -1;
    }
    m_isConnected = true;
    return 0;
}
```

The `output_error` function simply prints the message corresponding to the error using `FormatMessage()` function. However, I get the following output:

```
> Log: listen()
> ERROR: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.
```

Thus, the error should be caused by the call to `listen()` which is confusing. Could anyone explain me what's the cause of the problem? I bet it should be something easy to fix but I just don't seem to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is when calling `getaddrinfo()`, you are filling out the `hints` structure incorrectly.

You are assigning `SOCK_STREAM` to the `ai_protocol` field, and leaving the `ai_socktype` field set to 0.  `SOCK_STREAM` is defined as 1, which is the same value as `IPPROTO_ICMP`, which is commonly used with `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets.  So, `getaddrinfo()` is likely returning `addrinfo` entries whose `ai_socktype` field is set to `SOCK_DGRAM`.  You can't use `listen()` on a datagram socket, thus the `WSAEOPNOTSUPP` error you are seeing:

> If no error occurs, `listen` returns zero. Otherwise, a value of `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`.
>
> ...
>
> WSAEOPNOTSUPP
>   **The referenced socket is not of a type that supports the `listen` operation**.

You need to assign `SOCK_STREAM` to the `hints.ai_socktype` field instead, and set the `hints.ai_protocol` field to either 0 or `IPPROTO_TCP` (preferably the latter).

Also, `getaddrinfo()` returns an error code, just like `WSAStartup()` does. Don't use `WSAGetLastError()` to get its error code.

Aside from that, I see a number of other issues with your code.

- `SO_REUSEADDR` requires a `BOOL` (4 byte integer), not a `char` (1 byte). You are passing in a pointer to a single `char`, but are telling `setsockopt()` that you are passing in a pointer to an `int`.  `setsockopt()` will end up trying to read a value from stack memory you don't own.
- When your loop calls `closesocket()`, you should reset `sockfd` to `INVALID_SOCKET` as well, and then after the loop you should check for that condition instead of checking `ptr` for NULL.
- You should be calling `listen()` inside your loop instead of after it.  Just because you `bind()` a socket successfully does not guarantee you can open its assigned listening port.  You should keep looping until you actually open a listening port successfully.  You might also consider adding an extra log message after the loop to know which local IP/Port pair is actually listening, so you know what clients are then able to `connect()` to.
- When calling `WSAGetLastError()`, always call it *immediately* after a failed Winsock call.  If you call anything else beforehand, you risk resetting the error code, since `WSAGetLastError()` is just an alias for `GetLastError()`, which many APIs use.
- When calling `accept()`, you are using the `=` assignment operator instead of the `==` comparison operator when checking if `m_exchfd` is equal to `INVALID_SOCKET`.  Even after you fix that, if `accept()` succeeds, you are leaking `sockfd` since you lose track of it and don't call `closesocket()` on it.  If you are expecting only 1 client to connect, close the listening socket after the client is accepted.  Otherwise, store the listening socket in your class and close it after you close the accepted client socket.

With all of that said, try something more like this:

```
void OutputWinsockError(LPCWSTR funcName, int errCode)
{
    std::wostringstream msg;
    msg << L"> Log: " << funcName << L"()\n";
    OutputDebugStringW(msg.str().c_str());
    output_error(errCode);
}

void OutputWinsockError(LPCWSTR funcName)
{
    OutputWinsockError(funcName, WSAGetLastError());
}

int ConnectionManager::init_server() {

    // Log
    OutputDebugString(L"> Initializing server...\n");

    // Initialize winsock
    WSAData wsa;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (err != 0) {
        // Error initializing winsock
        OutputWinsockError(L"WSAStartup", err);
        return -1;
    }

    // Get server information
    struct addrinfo hints, *serverinfo, *ptr;
    SOCKET sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    err = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &serverinfo);
    if (err != 0) {
        // Error when getting server address information
        OutputWinsockError(L"getaddrinfo", err);
        // Call Cleanup?
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = serverinfo; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        // Create socket
        sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            // Error when creating a socket
            OutputWinsockError(L"socket");
            continue;
        }

        // Set options
        const BOOL enable = TRUE;
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&enable, sizeof(BOOL)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Error when setting options
            OutputWinsockError(L"setsockopt");
            if (closesocket(sockfd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // Error when closing socket
                OutputWinsockError(L"closesocket");
            }
            sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        // Bind socket
        if (bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Error on binding
            OutputWinsockError(L"bind");
            if (closesocket(sockfd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // Error when closing socket
                OutputWinsockError(L"closesocket");
            }
            sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }    

        // Listen on port
        if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Error on listening
            OutputWinsockError(L"listen");
            if (closesocket(sockfd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // Error when closing socket
                OutputWinsockError(L"closesocket");
            }
            sockfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(serverinfo);

    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        OutputDebugString(L"Error: Failed to launch server.\n");
        // Call Cleanup?
        return -1;
    }

    // Accept
    struct sockaddr_storage clientinfo;
    int size = sizeof(clientinfo);

    m_exchfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientinfo, &size);
    if (m_exchfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // Error when accepting
        OutputWinsockError(L"accept");
        if (closesocket(sockfd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            OutputWinsockError(L"closesocket");
        }
        // Call Cleanup?
        return -1;
    }

    m_isConnected = true;

    // is not storing sockfd, close it

    // m_listenfd = sockfd;
    if (closesocket(sockfd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        OutputWinsockError(L"closesocket");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to modify my program according to your comments, thanks a lot for them, but I still get the same error, now on both addresses found. Also, why do we use BOOL in setsockopt() function? According to the prototype of it, char should be used instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: What are the actual values of `ptr->ai_family`, `ptr->ai_socktype`, and `ptr->ai_protocol` when `listen()` fails? If they are not `AF_INET/6`, `SOCK_STREAM`, and `IPPROTO_TCP`, respectively, then something is going wrong. Oh, wait, I just saw another error in your code. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Read the [`setsockopt()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx). `SO_REUSEADDR` expects a `BOOL`. Don't be fooled by the signature of `setsockopt()` taking a `char*` pointer (logically, it should be using `void*` instead). That is a carry-over from historic times. It can actually take any kind of pointer, it just has to be type-casted. Just like with several other socket API functions, most notably the ones that are declared to take `sockaddr*` pointers but can actually take `sockaddr_XX*` pointers.

Comment: Changing `ai_protocol` to `ai_socktype` seems to have solved the problem. Thanks a lot!